# How to make calendar dropdown in C# and WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, calendar

How to make calendar drop-down when the cursor get top of it in C# and WPF?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Calendar control in Wpf: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/calendar?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

There's also a DatePicker control in Wpf: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datepicker?view=net-5.0

If for instance you want to just show the Wpf Calendar via your own button or something, then I recommend something like putting the Calendar inside of a Popup container (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup?view=net-5.0) and a ToggleButton (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton?view=net-5.0) to toggle the popup open and close.

Answer (score 0):

@ Aravinth.

Based on my understanding of your question, you could try to use the **Triggers** to make calendar drop-down, the XAML code is as follows:

```
<StackPanel>
        <DatePicker x:Name="datePicker" Width="100" Height="50"  >
            <DatePicker.Style>
                <Style TargetType="DatePicker">
                    <Setter Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="False"></Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="True"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="False"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DatePicker.Style>
        </DatePicker>
    </StackPanel>
```

The result:
[image]

If I misunderstand what you mean, please let me know.